# "Open with function" fails

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created a paint application using python and it is been generated as an installer (A desktop GUI).
When I open the image through my application it opens successfully and I am able to edit the image.

Now the problem is, when I try to open my application from the image for instance, select the image -> right click on the image -> go to open with-> select my paint application it opens with an error:

> IO [Error2] No such file or directory in: image1.

Can anyone suggest me which operation triggers when I open my application through an image.

Comment: That is platform-specific. You need to tell us if you are doing this in Windows, MacOS or Linux.

Comment: This issue is in Windows